# Are these insect eggs from Rosy Apple Aphids?

Tags: identification, fruit-trees, pests, aphids

It's that time of spring when all the bugs start coming out and the battle begins to protect my apple trees. I sprayed with a dormant spray earlier in the year but it looks like something is laughing at my best efforts still. Initially I thought it's Rosy Apple Aphids but I'd appreciate a second opinion since I'm not seeing the tell tale curling leaves. They are not widespread, I did a pretty thorough inspection of the trees and this is the only one with these eggs on them.

I'm in North America, hardiness zone 6.

[image: Close up macro photo. Small round white/grey eggs with brown spots and spirals]

For scale:
[image: For scale]

Comment: Overwintering red spider mite eggs (though they seem a little too large, not sure)?

Comment: Doing further research I'm now leaning towards these actually being either a type of butterfly or moth.

Comment: Seems like a good bet, but as to which...

Comment: Check out Peridroma saucia, or Pearly Underwings - its a moth that lays eggs that look like this. In the caterpillar stage, they're known as Variegated Cutworms... common in your area.

Comment: I think you are really really close. Dargida procinctus aka olive green cutworm, it's eggs look like an exact match. It's pretty far east for my area but they do exist here, it's just not overly common. Guess I'm checking all my leaves again to make sure I didn't miss any. Your help got me there @Bamboo so if you want to write it in the answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Don't worry about it... post the answer yourself!

Comment: Anubis and @Bamboo, one of you should really post an answer, to get this off the 'unanswered' list. Otherwise I will.

Comment: Oh alright, I give in...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest Peridroma saucia, or Pearly Underwings, a moth that lays eggs which look similar to this. As caterpillars, they're known as Variegated Cutworms, common in your area.

Having checked my suggestion, you've come up with Dargida procinctus - it'll be interesting to see what hatches out, if you've kept some of them somewhere!